# A Spring MVC controller that delegates to a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

One of my projects uses Spring MVC to handle URL mappings and dispatch logic. I have now to use a third party library which uses its own `HttpServlet` as the main entry point for its functionalities, but as it's an optional drop-in replacement for another library I can't just put the `<servlet>` declaration in the web.xml: I'd rather use a `Controller` and Spring profiles to switch between such implementations without having to edit the web.xml.

Is there anything offered OOTB by Spring to handle such cases? I don't seem to find it right away.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ideally, there would be no need to: the control flow will be dispatched to the servlet as part of the application logic, outside of the "normal" servlet dispatch. The steps in my mind would be `DispatcherServlet` -> `MyController` -> `ActualServlet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here just in case my approach can be useful to others.

There are two key factors I needed to consider:

- the proper initialization of the servlet
- give the servlet full control over the HTTP layer (e.g. setting HTTP headers, etc)

In my specific case there's no need for properly handling the servlet destruction, as it's a no-op.

I ended up writing a dedicated `Controller`, to be instantiated only if a specific Spring profile is activated, which takes care of instantiating and initializing the Servlet. Then, all the requests will be directly handled in a `void` handler method, as follows:

```
public class ServletDelegatingController implements ServletConfig {
    private final DelegateServlet delegate = new DelegateServlet();

    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception { 
        delegate.service(request, response);
    }



    // properly initializes the servlet
    public void setServletConfig(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        try {
            delegate.init(servletConfig);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failure while initializing the servlet", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The `delegating-servlet.xml` for the `DispatcherServlet` looks like the following:

```
<beans profile="custom">
    <bean id="cmisServiceFactory"
          class="com.foo.ServletDelegatingController"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since registering the third party servlet in your `web.xml` is a no-go, I think your best bet would be to create a singleton instance of the servlet in your `ApplicationContext`, and then create a custom view that delegates to said servlet's `service` method.

You can see an example of custom views in action in [this tutorial](http://www.zabada.com/tutorials/writing-a-custom-spring-mvc-view-rss).

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasoable. One has to retain the lifecycle with `init` and `destroy`.